# How to add unique mobile number function in Magento 2 registration form?

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation, mobile, registration

I used this link [How can i add a field mobile number at the time of customer registration form in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192537/how-can-i-add-a-field-mobile-number-at-the-time-of-customer-registration-form-in][1])
to add mobile number field in the registration form which works fine. But I need to validate mobile number to be unique, min and max of 10 digits.

Comment: can you get the solution?. I also have the same problem. If you have the solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data-validate="{maxlength:10, minlength:0}"
```

OR

```
data-validate="{rangelength:[0, 10]}"
```

And for unique you must do it in your controller

Comment: Can you pls guide me